# Need help with Business Communication

Tags: communication

I am a mid-level manager, English has been my second language. I find it unnerving to create formal communication for employee evaluations, interviews summaries, white papers etc. I end up dreading that work and spend a lot of time refining my writing and clarifying my thoughts to summarize. How can I get better and faster? Secondly, I think I also struggle with clarity of thought to summarize things or give a zoomed out view since I am so into the day to day running of my department. Greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I get better and faster?

Take a business writing course. You might find one at a local university or community college. A good course will have you writing a lot and will critique your submissions.

Practice. As with any skill, you get better and faster by doing it over and over again.

Comment: Or online, even more true now with the end of the world times.

Answer (score 3):

One thing I find helps is to keep a file of useful phrases and templates which can then be re-used over and over. As you build something like this up you eventually find that your compositions are mostly already written for you already. You're just changing a few details.

With one language I work in I have been complimented on my fluent style of writing more than once. But actually I don't have a style, I'm just mixing and matching phrases and concepts I've collected into a text file over several years. I thoroughly understand everything in the text file, but my fluency is much weaker if I were to hold a conversation in that language.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a native English speaker, but also find choosing the correct phrase, specifically in the context of employee evaluations, a very trying process.

There are books available which contains specific phrases which can be used in the context of employee evaluations.  The one I use is "Effective Phrases for Performance Appraisals" by James E. Neal Jr., though I haven't compared it to any others.

Using such a book has helped incredibly; essentially, when I review the various alternate ways of stating something, one of them will pop out as the most accurate way to verbalize my thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

As a native English speaker, I also "spend a lot of time refining my writing and clarifying my thoughts to summarize".  It happens to everybody and, while you might spend more time as a non-native English speaker, rest assured it happens to native English speakers too, so don't let that get you down.

Depending on your company, company culture, and locale, it may be acceptable for you to not use "the most correct" language when writing these reports.  In this case, don't stress it too much. Presumably those to whom you're presenting these documents are aware that you are not a native English speaker, and are willing to give you leeway in terms of minor errors in your English provided the message you are trying to deliver is clear.  I wouldn't sweat it too much.